# Sveltekit 2.0.1 - Async request "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

Tags: asynchronous, svelte, sveltekit

I'm a beginner at web development and sveltekit. I'm trying to do a async request in the following way:

```
<script context="module">
    export async function load({ fetch }) {
      const res = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
      const posts = await res.json();
  
      return {
        props: { posts }
      };
    }
</script>
  

<script>
    export let posts 
</script>

<div class="guides">
    <ul>
        {#each posts as guide}
            <a href="/">{guide.title}</a>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The file is located in src/about/+page.svelte

I keep getting the same error whatever I do. I tried to use the docs for sveltekit - load but it does not help me, I keep getting the same error (https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load)

Error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Module.each (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1841:31)
    at eval (/src/routes/about/+page.svelte:23:106)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
    at Object.default (root.svelte:44:40)
    at eval (/src/routes/about/+layout.svelte:26:36)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
    at Object.default (root.svelte:43:39)
    at eval (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/components/layout.svelte:8:41)
    at Object.$$render (/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.mjs:1876:22)
    at root.svelte:41:37
```

```
Creating the svelte app:
✔ Which Svelte app template? › Skeleton project
✔ Add type checking with TypeScript? › No
✔ Add ESLint for code linting? … No
✔ Add Prettier for code formatting? … No
✔ Add Playwright for browser testing? … No
✔ Add Vitest for unit testing? … No
```

Sveltekit version 2.0.1

Comment: That has changed in latest.

Comment: @chovy link to changes?

Comment: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-svelte